# How to show that this set is convex?

Tags: convex-analysis

> Prove that the following set is convex.
>
> $$X = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x_1^2 \leq x_2, x_1 \geq 0, x_2 \geq 0 \}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2) \in X$ and consider the line segment
\begin{align}
(x, y)= t(x_1, y_1)+(1-t)(x_2, y_2) \ \ \text{ for } \ \ 0\leq t \leq 1. 
\end{align}
Since $x_1^2 \leq y_1$ and $x_2^2 \leq y_2$ then 
\begin{align}
x^2= (tx_1+(1-t)x_2)^2 =&\  t^2x_1^2+(1-t)^2x_2^2+2t(1-t)x_1x_2 \\
\leq&\ t^2x_1^2+(1-t)^2x_2^2+t(1-t)(x_1^2+x_2^2)\\
\leq&\ t^2y_1+(1-t)^2y_2 + t(1-t)(y_1+y_2)\\
=&\ ty_1+(1-t)y_2 = y.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

The set is defined by the following [linear matrix inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_matrix_inequality) (LMI)

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & x_1 & 0\\ x_1 & x_2 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & x_1\end{bmatrix} \succeq \mathrm O_3$$

and, thus, it is convex.

Answer (score 0):

For any convex function f $X=\{(x_1,x_2)\in \mathbb R^{2}: f(x_1) \leq x_2, x_1 \geq 0, x_2 \geq 0\}$ is a convex set as you can verify immediately from the definition. The function $f(x)=x^{2}$ is convex.